# Can Logistic Normal distribution use mixture of Gaussian

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, logistic-regression, normal-distribution, gmm

In Topic Modeling can I use Logistic Normal distribution as a prior distribution and instead of a Gaussian distribution replace it with the Gaussian mixture component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model Logistic Normal distribution, mean, that you are using **generalized linear model** (**`GLM`**) and assume that errors follows the Normal distribution.The model using a Gaussian mixture component is **essentially** different from using Logistic Normal distribution.

Model using a **Gaussian mixture component** is type of  **generative models**, this mean you can't replace, `Logistic Normal distribution` with `Gaussian mixture component`, but you can have an entirely different model, with different (**assumption**, **parameters** and **equations**).